# Ivy generated pom without unnecessary dependencies

Tags: maven, pom.xml, ivy

I'm working on a plugin which uses ivy for dependency management. This plugin is used in a lot of other projects and a lot of people have started to use maven lately. Currently I'm using `ivy:makepom` to generate a pom. Due to ivys/mavens different handling of configuration/scopes now a lot of unneccessary dependencies are pulled in when using maven. Additionally some of them are really troublesome causing a lot of problems.

I would like to avoid creating a pom manually, so is there a already an automatic way to do this? Or do I've to start hacking IvyMakePom or some script myself?

**edit**:
To clarify my question, I'm looking for a automatic way to generate a pom based on ivy configuration which supports non-transitive dependencies through generating excludes.

Comment: What specifically is your issue with the makepom task? I think you need to provide more concrete examples of the problems you're having. The "mapping" child element enables control of which jars appear in the Maven scopes, which I would think gives you lots of control over the Maven POM file generation. Finally there is a "templatefile" option to the makepom task which I have never used, might be helpful with weird customizations.

Comment: Some dependencies are not resolved transitivly with ivy but with maven.

Comment: What do you mean? Ivy is able to resolve dependencies from Maven repositories....

Comment: Ivy does have the ability to disable transitive dependency resolution.

Comment: Yes, ivy can retrieve artifacts from Maven repositories with and without transitive dependencies. That's my point and question. what exactly are you trying to do? Ivy is a very flexible tool for managing depedencies, you need to outline which dependencies are "troublesome", and why. Otherwise we won't be able to assist.

Comment: It's the other way round, I've no trouble with ivy itself and it's working perfectly fine. Users of the plugin can choose between original ivy.xml and a ivy generated maven pom. But using maven results in different dependencies resolved.

Comment: I'm now starting to suspect that you have an ivy file in which you have explicitly switched off transitive dependencies. This is a feature not supported by Maven. You need to do is rely only on configurations to manage dependencies and then use these in the "makepom" task's mapping elements. You need to show your code. Finally, a more successful option might be to publish your builds into a Maven repository (Nexus?, Artifactory?). Maven repositories have become the defacto Java distribution format

Comment: Ok, you finaly got it, look at comment #2... Those dependencies should NOT be resolved transitivly and I know maven is going to do it anyway. So I need a way to exclude those dependencies automatically while generating a pom. Btw. ivy.xml, pom.xml jar are already published to a repository.

Comment: To paraphrase Jerry Maguire.... "Show me the code" :-)